# setTimeout with arrays to function does not work

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript, I would stop all these functions with this object, I tried but did not work never mechi with setTimeout and arrays:

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        var groupSvg = [svgManos, svgSuper, svgInnovation, svgEstatua, svgBrain, svgBalanza];

         groupSvg.stop();

}, 100);
```

I would like to stop all of these variables after 100 milliseconds.

Comment: You probably need to loop over the array and call `.stop()` on each and every element.

Comment: if you do something like : `svgManos.stop()` does it work ?

Comment: Are you referring to jQuery's [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method in your code? Can we assume that the items in your list are each DOM elements running some sort of animation?

Comment: is the variables inside that array are functions or objects? if not and you wish to simply remove them from the RAM use `delete groupSvg[0];` please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: "I would like to stop all of these variables after 100 milliseconds"... I never knew you could `stop` a variable.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
 svgManos.stop();
}, 100);`

works, but i need decrease this code...

Comment: Obviously, English is not the OP's first language. They at least posted some code and noted that they're new to JS, folks.

Comment: @user3249894 : In Javascript, an Array is an object, and it has its own set of methods. `.stop()` is not an Array method, so you have to loop through the contents of the Array and call `.stop()` on each individual member. See my answer for an example of how this might work. (There are more complicated ways to do this, but since you're new, I don't want to confuse you with some of the other options available to you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to rotate through your array and call a stop on each item, if they each have stop methods, similar to this:

```
// Dummy object for testing sake
var svgObject = function() {
    this.stop = function() { console.log("Stopping " + this); }
    return this;
};
// create dummy objects based on the base object
var svgManos = new svgObject(),
    svgSuper = new svgObject(),
    svgInnovation = new svgObject(),
    svgEstatua = new svgObject(),
    svgBrain = new svgObject(),
    svgBalanza = new svgObject();

    setTimeout(function(){
        var groupSvg = [svgManos, svgSuper, svgInnovation, svgEstatua, svgBrain, svgBalanza];
        // loop through the groupSvg array
        for(var svg in groupSvg){
            // do something to the current object from the array
            groupSvg[svg].stop();
        }
    }, 100);
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/E6syu/)

Answer (score 0):

If those are elements in the array, and it is the jQuery `stop` method that you are using, you should create a jQuery object from the array to run the method on all the elements with one call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var groupSvg = [svgManos, svgSuper, svgInnovation, svgEstatua, svgBrain, svgBalanza];
  $(groupSvg).stop();
}, 100);
```

Comment: That assumes the OP is using jQuery, of course. Separate question: how efficient is that? One of my tech leads told me that jQuery's array methods were not very fast, which is why he preferred underscore.js for array operations.

Comment: @mori57: That's not really one of the array methods in jQuery, that's the core of jQuery. A jQuery object is always an array of elements (even if there is only one element, or even zero), and most methods are applied to all item in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a couple of problems here:

- You're declaring an array instead of an object.
- Then you'r array obviously doesn't support that method (stop).

Declare this "later" function:

```
Object.prototype.later = function (msec, method){
   var arrs = new Array();  
   var that=this //keep this in inner func
   var args = 
   Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[2]);

   if (typeof method === 'string'){
        method = that[method];
   }

   setTimeout(function (){
        method.apply(that,args);
   },msec);

};
```

//source: from the "The Douglas Crockford JavascriptMaster class

then use the loop as @mori57 posted above

```
   for(var svg in groupSvg){            
        groupSvg[svg].later(100,"stop");
    }
```

Comment: I was truly hoping not to confuse the OP with prototype tricks. It's a nifty approach, but might be a bit confusing for someone who doesn't even know the difference between an Object and an Array, yet.

Comment: Hi yes you're right mori57, I'm just learning also js and since I have experiencie with OOP, I've been trying to use/answer using prototypes to get used to them, since js it's a prototype based language I think if @user3249894 is new to js also should give a chance to prototypes.

But more than that I tried to provide him/her a function to reuse.